# Ubuntu 20 terminal PHP script output

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal

Ubuntu 20 running on WSL, PHP 7.4

I am trying to debug code but cannot seem to get any output from the script.
To replicate:

myfile.php

```
<?php
echo "output text";
```

called from the terminal with

```
php myfile.php
```

The script runs but returns nothing.

Comment: Try `php ./myfile.php ; echo $? ;`. Does that print `0` ?

Comment: Also you can try to run `php -l ./myfile.php` and see what come up.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do int in right way.
You can tell php to execute a file like the following:

```
php myfile.php
```

... or

```
php -f myfile.php
```

You can check the following two things.

1. First one is that make sure you have installed php cli.
2. In your script try to put that line **#!/usr/bin/php** on very top of the file. So your file will looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo "output text";
```

Hope that helps you or at least gives you a right direction.

Comment: shebang is only needed when executing the file directly

Comment: can you advise why shebang is needed to output as the file runs without it but only this gives output as required

Answer (score -1):

For Debug your system needs some tools.

Run: `php -v` and see your php version.

You need to make sure you have module php installed.

Install: `phpx.x-cli`

Comment: What do you mean by "debug"? If this package was not installed, wouldn't that throw obvious error messages?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "_Ubuntu 20 running on WSL, PHP 7.4_" PHP version is right there in the question